# Deploying a meteor app using mongoLab and Heroku sandbox

Tags: mongodb, meteor, heroku, mlab

I've checked a couple of blogs. Specially [this](https://medium.com/meteor-js/deploying-and-hosting-meteor-on-heroku-mongolab-for-free-37050a3ebd7e#.ccowuw5v0) one about deploying and hosting meteor on heroku using mongolab.

I follow the steps below:

1. Create a meteor app (just for test v.1.4) `meteor create test`
2. `cd test`
3. `git init`
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -m "tst"`
6. `heroku create pikachu`
7. `heroku config:set ROOT_URL="https://pikachu.herokuapp.com"`
8. `heroku config:set MONGO_URL="pikachu:este@dsxxx.mlab.com:xxx/pikachueste"`
9. `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/Pushplaybang/meteor-buildpack-horse`
10. `git push heroku master`

After deployment the following error appears:

```
Starting process with command .meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js
```

Process exited with status 8

```
assert.js:93 
throw new assert.AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
at wrapPathFunction(/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/mini-    files.js:77:10)
at Object.<anonymus>(/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
```

...

```
Process exited with status 8
```

State changed from starting to crashed

I've notice that when I try to install mongodb addon in my sandbox:

```
heroku addons:create mongolab:sandbox
```

The process finish with:

```
!Please verify your account to install this add-on plan ...
```

Does the problem occur because I cannot install mongodb addon?
Is it possible to install mongodb addon in a heroku sandbox?
Is there any other alternative?

Thanks,

Comment: In order to verify account you need to add your credit card at Heroku's user profile details. You must do it even if you are going to use free plan at Heroku and mLab. Then you will be able to add mLab (MongoLab) addon.

Answer (score 1):

one of the reasons for this error:

`assert.js:93 
throw new assert.AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
at wrapPathFunction(/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/mini-    files.js:77:10)
at Object.<anonymus>(/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)`

Is that the node version being run on heroku is different from the one meteor is using. So far, Meteor is using node v.4.5.0 and the one your buildpack is using is below that. I've used that buildpack once and had the same error.

You can use the original [meteor buildpack horse](https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse) and deal with the

`Please verify your account to install this add-on plan ...` by removing the mongolab addon. I experienced these issues myself. You can refer to [this guide](https://meteorcoder.wordpress.com/2016/09/24/how-to-deploy-meteor-apps-with-heroku/) so it can be much clearer to you. It uses a fork of the original meteor buildpack horse without the mongolab addon. Just follow the guide and you'll be fine.